Why is Psalm 90, attributed to Moses, in the middle of the Psalms and not closer to the beginning?
Is Psalm 90 placed where it is because of the books of the Psalms following a theme, or is there a different reason? Moses wrote earlier than the rest of the writers of the Psalms, so it would seem that his writing would appear in the earlier Psalms.

We are not told so we do not know.  There is little or no rhyme or reason to the order of the psalms.

Note: The dates in the chart below for "Book 1" are based on traditional attributions. Many scholars assign much later dates, many of these plsams having been written during and after the Babylonian Exile.

Psalm 90 may have originally been Psalm 1 in what became the fourth section of the current Book of Psalms. Scholars have noticed that the Book of Psalms is divided into five sections, each of which ends with a closing doxology. Psalm 90 begins the fourth section, which may have once been a separate collection of hymns that was later compiled into the book that we have today. If so Psalm 90 should be understood as representing the first psalm of this collection, which included pss. 90-106.  In other words, as originally written, this particular book of psalms gave pride of place to our Psalm 90. Thus, its placement here is understandable.
